# Why is Java rounding this float

Tags: java, floating-point

Given what we know about floating point precision, why does this code:

```
float a = 0.1f;
System.out.println(a);
```

Print `0.1` and not `0.100000001`?

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it?

Comment: Wiki is your friend here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Comment: Because the default formatting removes the joke digits. Rather cute really. Note that the number you give is not an exact binary floating point value either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `println(a)` call to ends up calling [`Float.toString(a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString-float-), which says:

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of *m* or *a*? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type `float`. That is, suppose that *x* is the exact mathematical value represented by the decimal representation produced by this method for a finite nonzero argument *f*. Then *f* must be the `float` value nearest to *x*; or, if two `float` values are equally close to *x*, then *f* must be one of them and the least significant bit of the significand of *f* must be `0`.

Or said another way, since a IEEE 754 [single-precision floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) value only has from 6 to 9 [significant decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) precision, it won't include that final `1`, since it exceeds the precision of the stored value.

Here is code to show the numbers:

```
System.out.println(Math.nextDown(0.1f)); // prints: 0.099999994
System.out.println(0.1f);                // prints: 0.1
System.out.printf("%.15f%n", 0.1f);      // prints: 0.100000001490116
System.out.println(Math.nextUp(0.1f));   // prints: 0.10000001
```

Answer (score 8):

`0.100000001` wouldn't be exact either. If Java were to print this float completely unrounded, [it would print](https://ideone.com/ifBV7G)

```
0.100000001490116119384765625
```

which is unuseful for most floating-point use cases.

Either it doesn't round at all and you get `0.100000001490116119384765625`, or it rounds, and you need a rounding strategy. [The rounding strategy they picked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString(float)) is to print exactly enough digits after the decimal point to distinguish the float from any other float value, with a minimum of one digit. It is *not* necessarily enough to distinguish the float from any other *double* value.